# symfony 2 routes not found in production

Tags: routes, symfony

I have routes like: /, /login, /register, etc that work fine in dev environment.

At first i got 404 error when tried to access my site through app.php instead of app_dev.php

Then i followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631190/symfony2-access-same-route-in-production-as-development) and cleaned up my cache.

But now i'm getting a blank screen trying to access any of the registered  routes like app.php/ or app.php/login.

I found this message in prod.log:

```
[2012-02-24 11:27:05] request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /login" (uncaught exception) at /home/renat/www/ptracker/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 4564 [] []
```

Here is my routing.yml:

```
PtrackerTasksBundle:
resource: "@PtrackerTasksBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /

PtrackerAuthBundle:
resource: "@PtrackerAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

routing.yml in AuthBundle:

```
homepage:
pattern:  /
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerAuthBundle:Default:index }

register:
pattern:  /register
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerAuthBundle:Default:register }

login:
pattern:  /login
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerAuthBundle:Default:login }

activate:
pattern:  /activate/{username}/{salt}
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerAuthBundle:Default:activate }

login_check:
pattern:  /login_check
```

routing.yml in TasksBundle:

```
tasks:
pattern:  /tasks
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerTasksBundle:Default:index }

tasks_add:
pattern:  /tasks/add
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerTasksBundle:Default:add }  

tasks_view:
pattern:  /tasks/view/{id}
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerTasksBundle:Default:view, id : null }  

tasks_change_responsible:
pattern:  /tasks/change_responsible/{id}/{responsible}
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerTasksBundle:Default:change_responsible, _format: json }  

tasks_change_status:
pattern:  /tasks/change_status/{id}/{status}
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerTasksBundle:Default:change_status, _format: json }    

tasks_edit:
pattern:  /tasks/edit/{id}
defaults: { _controller: PtrackerTasksBundle:Default:edit }
```

What did i miss or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does `php app/console router:debug -e=prod` output?

Comment: [RuntimeException]                                                                
  Unable to write in the cache directory (/home/renat/www/ptracker/app/cache/prod)

Now it works with 777 rights :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, review in console list of routes (command `router:debug`).
If there you found your routers, then some troubles with clearing cache in my case I delete folder `app/cache` manually and it works.

For setting PROD environment without cache, in file `app.php` change to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Comment: The problem was in the incorrect folder's rights. When i set it to 777 it worked fine

Comment: the second parameter is for enable debug, in this case for the prod environment. [How to enable debug and disable caching](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/debugging.html)

Answer (score 9):

Try clearing cache on prod enviroment.

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app/console cache:clear

or

active mod_rewrite in

activate the directory:  nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

AllowOverride None
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
for
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/
```