# Why is route not recognized?

Tags: php, symfony

I have not used symfony2 before, but have inherited some code which I am trying to add to.

I have added a new route to the `UserController`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/pushsettings", name="pushsettings", defaults={"_format"="json"})
 * @View()
 */
public function pushsettingsAction(Request $request) {
    ...
}
```

When I run `./app/console router:debug`, I can see that the route is recognized
.
However when I try to access the route through a browser, I get a 404.

From looking at the log file, I have traced this to

```
cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php
```

This file is auto-generated, but for some reason my route is not being generated in here.

Manual editing of this file has fixed the issue - but why is the route not being auto-generated in here? Have I missed something?

If I then clear the cache, the route goes back to the 404 page again!

***EDIT:***

routing.yml looks like this

```
gp_api:
resource: "@AppApiBundle/Controller"
prefix:   /api
type:     annotation

gp_admin:
resource: "@AppAdminBundle/Controller/"
prefix:   /admin
type:     annotation

resetpsw:
pattern: /reset-password/{key}
defaults: { _controller: AppApiBundle:Default:resetpsw }

login:
pattern: /login
defaults: { _controller: AppApiBundle:Default:resetpsw }

login_check:
pattern: /login_check

logout:
pattern: /logout 

user:
pattern: /user
defaults: { _controller: AcmeMainBundle:Security:user }

admin_login:
path:      /admin/login
defaults:  { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Default:login }  

admin_twitter:
path:      /admin/twitter
defaults:  { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Default:twitter }    

admin_twitter_login:
path:      /admin/twitter_login
defaults:  { _controller: AppAdminBundle:Default:twitterLogin }    

admin_check:
pattern: /admin/admin_check

fos_oauth_server_token:
resource: "@FOSOAuthServerBundle/Resources/config/routing/token.xml"

fos_oauth_server_authorize:
resource:   "@FOSOAuthServerBundle/Resources/config/routing/authorize.xml"


gp_api_oauth_server_auth_login:
pattern:  /oauth/v2/auth_login
defaults: { _controller: AppApiBundle:Security:login }

gp_api_oauth_server_auth_login_check:
pattern:  /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
defaults: { _controller: AppApiBundle:Security:loginCheck }
```

In
    router:debug
I can see the route:

```
pushsettings                            ANY      ANY    ANY  /api/user/pushsettings
```

but this is not being generated in the cache file

Comment: Never edit files in the `cache` directory. That is only for speeding up the whole thing. Could it be that there is a rights issue in your cache directory? See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html about setting up permissions.

Comment: Another guess: You have edited the `prod` cache, and app:debug might work on `dev` cache. Check your environments, `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` and `app/console cache:clear --env=dev`.

Comment: I only edited it to see if it would fix the issue - and it did! The UserController file was already established with lots of other routes in it - all of which are being auto generated in the cache files - just the one that I added is not? Do I need to add specific permissions to a singe route somewhere?

Comment: Have you cleared the prod cache as mentioned by @k0pernikus ?

Comment: Is route annotation mapping enabled for this bundle ?

Comment: @VaN It says 'type: annotation' in routing.yml (see above). Is there anything else that needs doing to enable this?

Comment: @markt I don't think so. Anyway, if `router:debug` shows this route, everything is supposed to be OK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution here:

[symfony 2 routes not found in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427259/symfony-2-routes-not-found-in-production)

The solution was to change line in app.php (second parameter from 'false' to 'true'):

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

I don't understand why, but at least it works now!

***EDIT:***

This temporarily fixed the issue, but I later discovered that the issue was a bug in a different endpoint. When the routes are checked in the console, only the annotations are parsed, so they show up. However when the cache is being built, an error will stop the engine from moving on. Switching on debugging seems to enable the cache to be written despite errors.

I have now fixed the errors, switched off debugging and all is ok! :)

Comment: I don't think you want to activate debugging in the prod env. What is the output of `php app/console --env=prod router:debug` and `php app/console router:match --env=prod /api/user/pushsettings` ?

Comment: @skroczek - see the original question. The route is shown when I run these commands.

Comment: yes the one in the dev enviroment, where the kernel is also in debug mode, but not in the prod environmen. btw have you checked the permissions of the cache folder?

Comment: @skroczek - same in dev/prod environments. It's not permissions as all the files are being created in the cache folders. The issue is that the new routes are not showing except for when I make the change above.

Answer (score 0):

You should not edit that file by hand (it's auto-generated). Just clear/remove your cache and it should work.

Comment: Yes - done that - it doesn't work - as I said before all routes are recreated in the cache except the one that I have added??

Comment: Could you please post your routing.yml or routing_dev.yml files?

Comment: Edited my question with routing.yml - thanks for looking.

Comment: Actually in some cases, this is the solution to the question.