# symfony 2, demo not working on remote server

Tags: symfony, openshift

I created fresh symfony 2 app which includes AcmeDemoBundle. It works fine.

I commented out in `app_dev.php` so that it can be accessed from remote server (openshift cloud). On localhost it works without any problem. I git pushed to openshift, and `app_dev.php` worked as expected.

Then I moved demo routes to route.yml (for production).

On localhost `app.php` worked without any problem. So I git pushed to openshift but then `app.php` threw an error:

> failed to open stream Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Welcome/index.html.twig

So, I put back demo routes to `routes_dev.yml`, git pushed, but openshift error persists.

What might be the problem?

EDIT: The problem is that on my localhost path to twig template is "/var/www/html/jba/php/src/JBA/MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig" but on openshift it still looks to the same directory. But openshift dir layout is different, so it can't find the template. I guess I have to configure openshift to look at right directory. Just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the cache for the prod environment?

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

You might also have a look at the server logs/ the sf2 logs within app/logs/prod.log if this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I issued the following commands before uploading, but somehow cache seems to be not cleared yet.

```
php /var/www/html/jba/php/app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php /var/www/html/jba/php/app/console cache:clear
```

Only deleting prod and dev directories under app/cache explicitly helped.
See also 
[Symfony2: access same route in production as development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631190/symfony2-access-same-route-in-production-as-development)